# How does SpringCloudStream Kafka consume in bulk?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Native Kafka can be used KafkaConsumer.poll () to obtain messages in batches. How to configure it after integrating spring cloud starter stream Kafka (3.0.10. Release)? I didn't understand the official documents
Hope to give an example, thank you

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_batch_consumers

Set the `batch-mode` consumer binding property and use

```java
@Bean
Consumer<List<Foo>> input() {
    return list -> {
        System.out.println(list);
    };
}
```

Comment: Once you specify the @ bean, how do you receive a message?A single bar can be received by @ StreamListener. How should that batch be received?

Comment: The bean is all you need. Batch mode is not supported with the (deprecated) `@StreamListener` programming model, it is only available with the new functional model. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_bindings